# Django Cannot Be Accessed From Localhost

Tags: python, django, windows-7, localhost

It's kinda weird I cannot access django from localhost but I able to access it from local IP.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

then when I try to access from

[image]
[image]

My host file

```
127.0.0.1 lmlicenses.wip4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 lm.licenses.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 gc.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com ff.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com ie.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com
0.0.0.0 gc.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com ff.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com ie.kis.scr.kaspersky-labs.com
```

I'm guessing something wrong with windows firewall or kaspersky,but I don't know what to do.

I've add exception to port 8000 and python.exe too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot access localhost:8000 from my browser if I run `python manage.py runserver`

I don't know why that command cannot work in my laptop, but in my pc it just works.

====

ok, so my solution now is to use ipv6 and port 8000 which is

```
python manage.py runserver [::]:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try `http://0.0.0.0:8000` instead of `localhost:8000`

Default `localhost` value is `http://127.0.0.1`

If you see the runerver result you have :

```
starting developement server at http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

Because you told that django server start at `http://0.0.0.0:8000` when you run this command :

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: It's the same. I still cannot access even with http://127.0.0.1:8000/ nor http://0.0.0.0:8000/

Comment: why yo want to change IP address of django server ? just run the normal command `python manage.py runserver ` @RichardOctovianus

Comment: `Use runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 to make it listen on all interfaces` from Django official documentation https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/396

Answer (score 1):

I'm also beginner to django, but I needed following things in order to run the server:

1. In `settings.py`, added `ALLOWED_HOSTS` as 
   `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
       'elearning.com'
   ]`

   where elearning.com is my hostname. You can have multiple hosts separated with comma.
2. Used following command to run the server:
   `python manage.py runserver [::]:8000` 
    or 
    `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` 
   or 
    `python manage.py runserver 0:8000`.

   It will now listen to all interfaces. Read Django doc [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/396).
3. Browsed to given hostname. In my case, it is http://elearning.com:8000/

I tried writing IP in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` but it didn't work, I could not open http://192.168.x.x:8000 in browser. Can anyone please correct me?

Answer (score 0):

simply execute

```
python manage.py runserver
```

automatically you can access by localhost and for the extern access you could have access if not are it's locked the port 8000, for access to django admin use the next url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
```

Comment: even with just "python manage.py runserver" i cannot access through localhost:8000 in my browser. that's why i use 0.0.0.0:8000 to be able accessed from my lan ip

Answer (score 0):

How your host file end up like this ?? . Can you test something.

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

My host file see everything is commented out. Can you do the same with your `hosts file` and give it a Try .. .

Comment: seems nothing to do with hosts file, I tried it before

Comment: Well in my Case it did.

Answer (score 0):

In the **settings.py** file in your project folder,
add **'0.0.0.0'** to the **allowed host** list.
Then save the file and run the command.Guess will work.