# Could not browse django site

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm trying to follow the the django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) but when when I get to the `python manage.py runserver` step, I can't browse http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in chrome or IE. But when I wget in bash, I was able to get the html from http://127.0.0.1:8000. I'm using windows 10 anniversary edition and I'm using virtualenv.

Comment: What do you get when you visit 127.0.0.1:8000 in your browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639612/django-cannot-be-accessed-from-localhost

Comment: I get the same error as the link above (@Corgs). But I don't think we have the same problem. I tried his solution but it didn't work on my pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you use wget in bash I'll assume you aren't using windows, so maybe it's another machine.

When you tell django to listen on `127.0.0.1` it will only accept local connections.

Now to open django to everyone you'll have to run it as such :

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Also you'll have to make sure your gateway accepts connections on port 8000 and forwards them to your computer, where django runs. (see port forwarding).

Comment: I'm actually using windows 10, the anniversary edition has a bash, i think it's ubuntu inside windows 10.

Comment: I'm actually in a domain. I don't think I have any access to port forwarding settings. Is there another alternative to do this? By the way I tried it at my home pc that's not on a domain, It works there, I can browse the django site. So I really think it has something to do with my work pc being in a domain. I'm hoping I can get an alternative way to access the site. I know that it's running because I can get the html texts when I run wget on it.